# Best way to add new css rules with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am dynamically inserting some html on a web page (after I detect an event from the user). This html needs some css styling and I am wondering what is the cleanest way to do it, using jQuery. I am not the website developer, so I can't add those rules to the original css.

Assume I have already inserted some html without styling, including a `formElement` class. I can write in my document a new `<style>` block, for instance:

```
my_html =  '<style type="text/css">';
my_html += '   .formElement {';
my_html += '       display: block;';
my_html += '       width: 240px;';
my_html += '       position: relative;';
my_html += '       padding: 4px 0;';
my_html += '   }';
my_html += '</style>';
my_html = $(my_html);
$('body').prepend(my_html);
```

Or, I can use the `css` method:

```
$('.formElement').css({
    'display': 'block',
    'width': '240px',
    'position': 'relative',
    'padding': '4px 0'
});
```

Which solution is the best/cleanest?

**EDIT:**

As I can't directly add the rules in the CSS, I will stick with the `css` method of jQuery. Some other related questions provide solutions as well:

- [Create a CSS rule / class with jQuery at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime)
- [Changing CSS Rules using JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431116/changing-css-rules-using-javascript-or-jquery)

I can't really use jQuery plugins, but if I could, I would certainly use [jQuery.Rule](http://flesler.blogspot.fr/2007/11/jqueryrule.html)

Thank you all for your precious help.

Comment: Your second code will not work if you add more elements with that class later.

Comment: Also consider that second option will have more specificity as it is inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, the best way may be neither. If I had to pick one, the jquery `css` method would be my choice, just because it's cleaner, however, consider this alternative for better performance and cleaner looking code:

Create CSS classes to append to your elements when needed. For example:

```
.formElementAlpha {  
  width:240px;
  padding:4px 0;
}
.formElementBravo {
  width:400px;
  height:50px;
  padding:20px 0;
  line-height:50px;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

then, with jquery, when you need it:

```
$('.formElement').addClass('formElementAlpha');
```

or

```
$('.formElement[name="bigUsernameInput"]').addClass('formElementBravo');
```

I would reserver the jQuery `css` method for instances where you need to modify a specific element based on some sort of user interaction or other dynamic event that requires you to use the value of your JavaScript variables to determine the styles you are applying. Since it looks like you already know how you want to style them, let CSS do the work.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I guess you are right about not liking either methods. I like what you propose but the thing is I am not the website developer and so, I can't create the CSS classes. I can only interact with the page through javascript... But I'll keep that in mind for other projects!

Comment: Your best bet may be to adopt the method listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2076345/1279409), then, and it works in any browser I've ever come across.

Answer (score 10):

Don't mix css and js together, especially if your properties don't contain computed or dynamic values: just define a CSS class

```
.mystyle {
    display: block;
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 4px 0;
}
```

and set the class

```
$('.formElement').addClass('mystyle');
```

Comment: Which of course bears the question, what is the best way to define a new css class with jquery?

Comment: Fabrizio solution does the same of what the OP needs and does the same as both of his options. It will be faster than the ones the OP posted. Instead of giving style proprieties to an element, he is adding a class that contains the proprieties to an element. Same thing, better code organization.

Comment: @AndréSilva absolutely. We are in 2013, time for markup, css and script soup is long gone. :)

Comment: @BeniBela: That question was answered very well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2076345/1279409).

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
$('.formElement').css({
        'display': 'block',
        'width': '240px',
        'position': 'relative',
        'padding': '4px 0'
    });
```

Comment: It's just hard to do @media queries this way when it's necessary*

Answer (score 2):

Your second option:

```
$('.formElement').css({
    'display': 'block',
    'width': '240px',
    'position': 'relative',
    'padding': '4px 0'
});
```

This is by far the cleanest solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [.css( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('.formElement').css({
    'display': 'block',
    'width': '240px',
    'position': 'relative',
    'padding': '4px 0'
});
```

this is best among the solutions that you have provided.

**HOWEVER** I would go for creating a class with all that properties say `yourCSS` and add the class to that element:

```
$('.formElement').addClass('yourCSS');
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<style id="customCSS"> ... </style>
```

JS

```
my_html += '   .formElement {';
my_html += '       display: block;';
my_html += '       width: 240px;';
my_html += '       position: relative;';
my_html += '       padding: 4px 0;';
my_html += '   }';
$('#customCSS').html(my_html)
```